# GoogleMap is not zooming at the right location

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I have to develop an app to show locations of a restaurant on a Map when you want some details about it. The overall experience works but zoom seems out of bounds.

By default, I am showing a high view but the location is correct:

[image]

I tried to apply a zoom using the code below:

```
 private fun locationLocationOnMap(lat: Double, lon: Double, name: String?) {
        val place = LatLng(lat, lon)
        mapGoogle.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(place).title(name))
        mapGoogle.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place))
        //mapGoogle.animateCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo( 11.0f ))
    }
```

the  `animateCamera` when used is way of the location like it's not center at all.

the layout is defined as:

```
               <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Any ides way? As it's a restaurant, I need have a more "street" level view

Comment: Did you ever try mapGoogle.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(...))?

Comment: try with this : `mapGoogle.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place, 12.30f))`

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? In addition to the above comments, I suggest that you check the official Maps SDK for Android documentation for more instructions and details about zoom: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views#zoom